# SAS issue with Rename variable

Tags: sas

I have a dataset with 6 character variables including Day5,Day6,Day7,City1,City2,City3.
I am trying to rename Day5 which was extracted as i__Day5 after importing txt file into SAS. The variable i__day5 is not getting renamed to day5 and so it does not shows any observation for this variable.

```
data subset ;
set subset ;
rename i__Day5 = Day5;
run;
```

Thanks.

Comment: I see that your question has a single underscore, whereas the variable in the snippet has two. Are you sure that the name of the variable is correct? What's in the log? Anything like `... has never been referenced`?

Comment: I have added the underscores in the other two variable references in above question. There is no error. It is not taking the i__Day5 variable

Comment: Just a suggestion - - run a `proc contents` on that table. Also, please post your what's on your sas log. Would be helpful for us to understand, and not guess.

Comment: Bad idea to read in SUBSET and write out SUBSET , overwriting it. It means even if your code worked the first time it is run, if you rerun the step it will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tom mentioned your problem likely stems from overwriting the original table with the modified data, and then trying to submit your code to run again.

It will work the first time when the variable `i__Day5` exists, but on running it a second time, the variable will no longer exist as it has already been renamed.

To avoid this issue never re-use table names.  This code would be better:

```
data subset2 ;
  set subset ;
  rename i__Day5 = Day5;
run;
```

Space is cheap so there's no real downside to doing this, plus it gives you an easy way to compare the table before/after running the code.

The only other issue that this could be is that you are viewing field labels and not field names. As samkart mentions, you can verify the actual field names by running a `proc contents` against your table.